# Добавление данных с формы в новоую колонку mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

У меня страница логина пользователей. На ней есть формы ввода, с которых данные записываются в базу. После логина пользователь переходит на `profile` страницу. На ней я создал одну форму ввода для добавления описания, и колонку под него в бд, но с этой формы ичего не записывается.

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s', 
                    (email, password))

        account = cur.fetchone()

        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account[0]
            session['email'] = account[3]
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))
        else:
            return render_template('error.html')

    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        print(session['id'])
        print()
        print(session['email'])
        print()
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'])
        if request.method == 'POST':
            id= session['id'] 
            texts = request.form['text']
            sql_update ="""UPDATE data 
            SET texts=? 
            WHERE url = ?""" 
            params =(texts,id) 
            cursor.execute(sql_update, params)
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()
            return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'], texts=texts)

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

`profile.html`

```
your session id is: {{ id }}
your session email is: {{ email }}
your session text is: {{ texts }}

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Add"></form>
</form>
```

Значения `id` и `email` получаю, а вот строка `text` пустая, т.к. в бд ничего не записалось.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, к тому пользователю, который уже залогинился

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, я не совсем понимаю. я думал, что это с помощью сессии видно и можно сразу добавлять описание. Можете на моем примере показать?

Comment: попробуйте с последними изменениями. Давайте продолжим обсуэжение в чате https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109235/discussion-on-answer-by-vadim-sharoikin-------

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, я отметил ваш ответ как верный для добавления данных в бд. можете по другому вопросу подсказать? вот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140484/python-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-html-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос проверил обычным скриптом через cmd. В фласке тоже должен работать. Выглядеть должен примерно так (сам синтаксис запроса корректен)

```
id= session['id'] 
texts = request.form['text']
sql_update ="""UPDATE users.data 
SET texts=? 
WHERE id = ?""" 
params =(texts,id) 
cursor.execute(sql_update, params)
mysql.connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109235/discussion-on-answer-by-vadim-sharoikin-------).