# python не получает значение из html формы

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть метод `profile` который должен получать текст из html формы и заносить его в базу данных но он почему-то не видит его. Я проверял с помощью вывода в консоль, но ничего не выводится. В чем может быть проблема,

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']


        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s', 
                    (email, password))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account[0]
            session['email'] = account[3]
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))
        else:
            return render_template('error.html')

    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        return render_template('profile.html', id=session['id'], email=session['email'])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        description = request.form['description']
        print(description)
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        account = cur.fetchone()
        session['id'] = account[0]
        cur.execute('UPDATE users.data SET description = %s WHERE id = %s', (description, session['id']))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        print(description)
        return render_template('profile.html', description=description)
    else:
        return 'NO'

    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

`profile.html:`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="description">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <form action="/profile" method="POST"> ?

Comment: @D.Violet, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: а print(request.form) вообще что-то выдаёт?

Comment: @D.Violet нет, вот в этом проблема. абсолютно не понимаю, почему он не видит форму. в методе `login` все норм, а при регистрации тем более, но тут странно..

Comment: а если elif request.method == 'POST': ?

Comment: @D.Violet тоже делал. Даже через try catch

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109296/discussion-between-d-violet-and-abby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def profile():
if request.method == 'POST':
print(request.form)
return 'OK', 200

elif request.method == 'GET':
return render_template('profile.html')
```